# Question about passive voice and modal verbs

Tags: passive-voice, past-perfect, past-simple

In South Park s19e02, there is the following dialog:

```
1) - The X has been fu**ed to death. 
- Yes! Yes!
- What? Are you sure? 
- What is it, Thomas? 
2) - The X got fu**ed to death, darling.
```

The first sentence seems to be Present Perfect, Passive voice.

But what tense is used in the second sentence?

Is it Present Simple, or Passive voice with *got* used as a Modal verb?

Comment: Sentence 2 is in Simple Past and it has a  "get-passive".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Got* in example 2 is the simple past tense of *get*.

*Got* is never a modal.

*X get(s) Y'ed* means "X undergoes an event where the end result is that we can say X is Y'ed."

> I got blessed with 20 dollars = I underwent an event where the end result is that I am blessed with 20 dollars

There is *have got*, and the *got* here in this expression emphasizes *have* in any of its meanings but not where *have* is being used in a perfect tense.  *Had got* doesn't work.

> I have 10 dollars.
>
> I have got 10 dollars.
>
> I have to talk to John.
>
> I have got to talk to John.
>
> I have talked to Jerry.
>
> I have got talked to Jerry (doesn't work).

Answer (score 2):

"Got" is a form of "get", which is not a modal verb. It is a [light verb](https://people.ucsc.edu/~chanmill/cause.pdf).

As CowperKettle says, sentence 2 is in the (simple) past tense, the same tense as a sentence like "The Canadian president died." It is a "[get-passive](http://www.grammaring.com/the-passive-with-get)".

Comment: It's not an auxiliary at all.  It doesn't participate in subject–auxiliary inversion (*Did I get hit by a car?* but not *\*Got I hit by a car?*) or negate (*I didn't get hit by a car* but not *\*I got not hit by a car*) or pass any other tests that would indicate auxiliaryhood.